# 0V at Subtractor Circuit Input

Tags: amplifier

I put together the following simple subtractor circuit:
[image: subtractor]

Problem is, I see 0V at the non-inverting input of U2, no matter what.

I added U1 (buffer), moved positions in the breadboard, removed C3, and swapped out the LMP7721 in exchange for an LM324 as attempts to fix this, but to no avail. If either R9 or C3 are connected to GND, I see 0V all along that node. It works just fine in LTSpice, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

What am I missing?

**EDIT - 2/Oct**

Shown below is my previous design, which worked just fine (I've only changed it to try and subtract out ambient noise). I tested my WE against this circuit and I see the voltage range I expect.

[image: old circuit]

Comment: I think you overlooked the CMVR is Vcc-1V  and a few other choices in biasing and design simplification.

Comment: Tony- my VCM should be between 0V and 1.1V. The LMP7721's datasheet shows a CMVR of -0.3V to +1.5V if VCC = 2.5V, and my VCC = 3.3V. This seems like it should be fine.

Comment: What is source We on your proto board? Is its output non zero?

Comment: If U1 out is also 0V trace backwards if not then forwards.

Comment: post the picture of your actual implementation too

Comment: sstobbe- WE should see the voltage range listed in the simulation for that source, and it does when I test against my old circuit (post edited to show old circuit).
Tony- in a way, I have, by swapping out the electrodes (RE and WE) and testing against the old circuit. That being said, my circuit troubleshooting skills are a little weak.
next-hack- unfortunately, I pulled it apart, but I may rebuild it tomorrow.

Comment: What is between RE and WE?

Comment: Bruce- just a chemical buffer that induces a static potential on the surface of the WE. Changing the chemical buffer changes the value of the potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up not being a circuit problem at all, but I wanted to close the question out. Turns out the REF electrode style I was using was effectively a floating output (not actually connected to my "ground" thru solution) and that allowed all kinds of fun things to happen.

Anyways, solved.

Comment: Good work. You are allowed to "accept" your own answer. This is a help to anyone else reading to know that it actually answers the question.